# Sending a JS file in Flask

Tags: python, flask, download

Currently, I have a static JS file which is returned to user on a specific api request. The code which handles this is as follow

```
@app.route('/js/<path:path>')
def send_js(path):
    return send_from_directory('js', path)
```

However, What i want to do is modify the current JS file (add some user specific modifications) and then return it to the user. Being a Java developer, I would have first read the file, made the in-memory modification and write those bytes to response object.

However, while trying to google `send_file` and `send_from_directory` i couldn't find a way where i can provide content of the file?

How should i implement this in flask?

Answer (score 0):

you can use StringIO.

```
@app.route('/js/<path:path>')
def send_js(path):
    path = secure_filename(path)
    with open(os.path.join("js", path), "rb") as fd:
        data = fd.read()
    #do stuff with data
    return send_file(StringIO(data), attachment_filename=path)
```

StringIO create a file-like object from a string

The imports are the follows:

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
from io import StringIO
```